# Nested arbitrary object does not work in javascript

Tags: javascript

Why does this not work? I get an error that this action is not supported by my IE9.

```
var data = new { selectedUnitKey: { value1: 1, value2: 2} }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `new` :

```
var data = { selectedUnitKey: { value1: 1, value2: 2} }
```

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) :

> The new operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or
>   of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.

You use new like this when you define your "class" :

```
function SomeClass(unitKey) {
     this.selectedUnitKey = unitKey;
}
var data = new SomeClass({ value1: 1, value2: 2});
```

Comment: ah... I got confused with the c# anonym objects... Thanks man.